# In android, how do I dynamically swap a fragment by button click or other event?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm stuck at a sore point: fragments.

Here's a reference of the layout

[image]

I'm trying to swap out fragment C with fragment D upon button click. Fragment A and B needs to stay without refreshing.

It looks like I stopped at having it load a fragment without throwing away the old fragment, leading to fragment D appearing above fragment C, with C still visible.

How can I do this?

Comment: you need to replace  existent fragment with another one ??

Comment: @mohammedmomn Yes. Upon onClick, fragment C should disappear and fragment D should appear with its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Fragment API let you to make some transactions in it like add new one , delete and replace one with another one that's will help you to build flexible UI design based on your device size ,

and here some guide for you :

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture09/lecture09.html

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/04/replace-fragment.html

and if you facing any problem in code  tell me to discuss in it

Comment: I've been skimming the android documentation for the UI, but it's based on a way different design than I am looking for.

Your last link works wonders, however! I'll be looking at the code later and see what I can figure out. Thank you so much!

Comment: So the last link worked perfect. It helped me create the over-all layout and lets me configure my buttons to switch out the middle fragment. The issue I'm facing now is that I'm not able to add a onClickListener to the main container. In one of the fragment (the first one loaded) I've added a button, but I have no clue how to set an onclicklistener to this. In an activity - fine, but not in these dynamic fragments.

Comment: if you talking about communicating between fragments and each other components , we using callback  methods and here link explain this idea , 
http://laaptu.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/android-effectively-communicating-between-fragments-and-activities-to-avoid-null-pointer-exception-errors/

feed me if you get your idea

Comment: I tried following laaptu's instructions, but they seem to be a bit for the more experienced ones. I decided to look through the android documentation and found the decent, albeit small, documentation on callbacks here http://goo.gl/zdXMOF

This seems to be the essentials that laaptu is referring to, in a bit of an easier-to-understand way. This also seems to work up until having to implement it, in which case I'm stuck at implementation. Uri noteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ArticleColumns.CONTENT_URI, id); is what I don't get. What is ArticleColumns and how can I ID the buttons?

Comment: ArticleColumns it is custom object created not related to android API because the samples of code here are not completed , it just explain for the idea

Answer (score 3):

There is a call within FragmentTransaction to replace the fragment in the container. You just need to have a designated container hold the place where c and d will go, and then upon button click do something like:
    `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, "FragD");`

Comment: Keep in mind that you cannot remove or replace fragments that weren't added dynamically (using the DragmentManager) in the first place.

Comment: In order for this to work, you can't have specified the fragments in xml. They have to be added/replaced into something like a `FrameLayout`.